# How to dynamically/Programmatically grant access a folder on AWS S3 bucket to specific application users

Tags: amazon-s3

Our Application stores bunch of reports on AWS S3 bucket. 
These are html reports dumped into the S3 bucket in the format:

```
Report1/index.html
           /css/*.css
           /img/*.jpg
Report1/subpage.html
           /css/*
           /img/*
           /JS/*
Report2/index.html
            ...
            ...
```

Is there a way to grant application users access to specific reports(say 'Report1'), which they can browse directly on the web?

Currently we are using Presigned URLs for each file, but generating PreSigned URLs for every file within the report folder is tedious for the server.
Is there any other way?

Comment: What do you mean by "tedious for the server"? Are you saying that it over-taxing the server? It should only take a couple of lines of code to generate a pre-signed URL.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think the idea is that there could be dozens of files that need to be presigned and then downloaded. OP seems to want a solution that doesn’t require downloading a local copy of the file (inferred from “browse directly on the web”).

Comment: @Mahesh How do you define your "users"? Do they have IAM User credentials, or are they authenticating through your web application?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, auth is done via a web app. Fyi, its a aspnetcore webapp..

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, "tedious for the server" - There are too many files in the report, and too many signed urls needs to be created and served. 
JoeyKilpatrick is correct in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Pre-signed URLs** are the correct method. They enable your application to first determine whether a user should be permitted access, and then it can grant time-limited access.

Answer (score 0):

I’ll give two options. Choosing between them would depend on the details of your use case.

**Option 1:**

Give the user access through IAM. An example policy for this use case would be

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/Report1/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Option 2**
Use `html-webpack-plugin` to create one single Report1.html for each report and then use presigned links.

Personally, I think Option 2 is more elegant but Option 1 will be a little more flexible. Also Option 1 will require the use of an IAM role or user and Option 2 will not.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try option 2 and get back to you. @Joey Kilpatrick